# How to display Chinese characters in classic ASP using response.write

Tags: unicode, asp-classic, response, cjk, chinese-locale

How to display Chinese characters in ASP using response.write?

```
<%
  Response.CodePage=51936
  Response.Charset="UTF-8"
  Response.ContentType = "text/html"
  Dim Msg
  Msg="简"
%>
<%Response.Write Msg%>
```

Comment: Try `Response.CodePage=65001`

Answer (score 3):

[Codepage 51936](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Web_Encodings) is EUC-CN. Not UTF-8, which is 65001.

Comment: Response.Write always emits non Chinese characters no matter the codepage set

Comment: What's the encoding of your text editor? The whole tool chain must be in the same encoding...

Comment: I am using UTF encoding without BOM. Should all the pages have the same encoding. Actually what I am doing is defining that needs to be translated in a single page and including them in other pages. other pages might have different encoding.

Comment: You're setting yourself up for more pain than you should. Please realize that in static strings like `Msg="简"`, 简 will be in whatever encoding your .asp page is. Which means that `Response.CodePage=XXXXXX` and `Response.Charset="xxxx"` will have to be in the same encoding...

Answer (score 0):

This long quiet question, still needs a verified solution!
I was successful in displaying Chinese and Korean characters from a UTF-8 encoded Classic ASP script. 
All I did was simply add the meta charset tag in the head of the document, like so:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<% 
  chinese="欢迎" 
%>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  ...
</head>
<body>
  <%= chinese %>
</body>
</html>
```